# symfony2 - hide 'web' directory from url

Tags: .htaccess, symfony

I've deployed a symfony2 project to a subdirectory in a shared hosting.

I only can access by urls like:

- http:mydomain/subdirectory/web
- http:mydomain/subdirectory/web/page1
- etc...

I want access by urls like:

- http:mydomain/subdirectory
- http:mydomain/subdirectory/page1

I only have the default .htaccess in web directory with this rules:

RewriteEngine On

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^app\.php(/(.*)|$) %{ENV:BASE}/$2 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule .? - [L]

RewriteRule .? %{ENV:BASE}/app.php [L]
```

Can someone tell me how can I do that, please?

Tkanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must configure your webserver to use `web` as the document root of your application, not the base directory where you’ve installed Symfony. For Apache, that would be the `DocumentRoot` directive.

```
# wrong
DocumentRoot /var/www/MY-SYMFONY-SITE/

# right
DocumentRoot /var/www/MY-SYMFONY-SITE/web/
```

If you don’t have access to that directive, your ISP should provide a tool to set the document root, e.g. through a web interface. If you cannot change the document root at all, you should not run Symfony on that server.

If you try to run Symfony with the installation directory as document root (which is theoretically possible), you’re creating a huge security problem, because sensitive information, such as the config files in the `app` directory will be world readable.

Comment: Thanks @lxg . Yes. I just saw that the ISP gives me the ability to change it. Thank you very much!